# Picture editor- sound designer relationship/ workflow

Tags: picture-editor, sound-designer, relationship, workflow

I am a film editing student and I have never worked with a specialist sound designer before. I want to know about the relationship between a picture editor and a sound designer. In other words, I would like to know what is the workflow of picture and audio post production like.

Answer (score 1):

You can discuss scenes where sound can be more descriptive than picture, for example. I highly recommend to read this book, at least the first chapters.
http://www.amazon.co.uk/Sound-Design-Expressive-Effects-Cinema/dp/0941188264

Answer (score 0):

There is great info in Dialogue Editing for Motion Pictures